# Table Deprecations Question

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

I keep getting this warning with the line of code below, 'initWithFrame:reuseIdentifier:' is deprecated.  Not really sure what that is referring to.

```
 cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deprecated means that the method will soon be unavailable in the future sdk. You can always check what you should use instead by just finding this method in the docs.

> initWithFrame:reuseIdentifier:
>   Initializes and returns a table cell
>   object. (Deprecated in iOS 3.0. Use initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:
>   instead.)

This particular method was deprecated by

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
```

Comment: Actually, deprecated means that the method is still available but will soon disappear in a future version of the SDK. The compiler is warning you to update your code in order to stay current. Otherwise, your app will break upon some system rev in the near future.